# How to enable both front and rear Cameras on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to implement a function, which can open the front camera and rear camera on the phone at the same time, and use two SurfaceViews to preview respectively. This function is implemented using camera2 API or Camera API, I don't know how to do it. If you have a good idea, please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Relatively few devices have the hardware resources to run both cameras at once.

However, those devices that can handle it up to a certain resolution can declare so via https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager?hl=en#FEATURE_CAMERA_CONCURRENT

Read the documentation there to see what the restrictions are. But the actual code is straightforward - open both cameras, configure the capture sessions for both, and start running them:

> For concurrent operation, in chronological order : - Applications must first close any open cameras that have sessions configured, using CameraDevice#close. - All camera devices intended to be operated concurrently, must be opened using openCamera(String, CameraDevice.StateCallback, Handler), before configuring sessions on any of the camera devices.

> Each device in a combination, is guaranteed to support stream combinations which may be obtained by querying getCameraCharacteristics(String) for the key CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_MANDATORY_CONCURRENT_STREAM_COMBINATIONS.

If the device doesn't support this feature, it may still allow for simultaneous front-back use, but it's unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible technically

you can open only one camera at same time

Comment: While most devices don't support it due to hardware limitations, it's not disallowed by the camera API.  But it requires the device to have enough hardware.